# xml not working on device

Tags: android, xml

On my Nexus 4, my app looks like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atre3.png) . The app is looking perfectly normal on the eclipse WYSIWYG screen. The xml file for this is: (as the original is very long, I've removed all the textviews and buttons as I thought it was irrelevant to the issue)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100"
android:background="@drawable/testbg">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="33"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    ---- bunch of textviews ---

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="57"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    ---- more TextViews ----

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    ---- 3 buttons ----       

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Why is this happening? Is the xml just corrupted?

Comment: Do you have your WYSIWYG set to 4.7" 1280x720 xhdpi?  In the latest tools you can just set it to "Galaxy Nexus" and that should be an accurate representation of your Nexus 4.

Comment: yep, it looks fine on all of the options

Comment: Are you using sp or dp sizes for your fonts?  I've had problems with the editor not properly displaying font sizes for some device configurations and it's taken a bit of guess and test.  It's not so much WYSIWYG as much as it's WYSIWY(might)G.

Comment: they're all around 15 to 20dp but I don't think that's too relevant because it was working before with that font size

Comment: otherwise, you can't use "orientation" in relativelayout ?

Comment: I got rid of that and it still doesn't work